# How to use github secrets in firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, github, github-actions

I am exploring github secrets along with github Actions to deloy firebase function on cloud. In my app i am using lot of config value which should not be plain text in application so hiding these info i research about github secret that how it is working and can get the secrets in Workflow while building and deployment of application. I am little confused that is it possible to use github secrets as a application secret store if yes then howit should work if i have a firebase function and going to deploy on cloud?
Is there any example then please share.

PS: i am using github action to deploy my function on cloud when git push happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub secrets is not designed to be used as an application secret store. Only the GitHub Actions app can retrieve and decrypt the secret values so they can be sent to the runner with the job.

We currently do not and do not have a plan to enable other apps to retrieve and decrypt the secret values.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I have assumed. Thanks