# Can We Access Github secrets variable in our firebase cloud functions at run time? if Yes, Please explain the process with example

Tags: firebase, github, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, git-secret

```
    
    function GetPolicy(timeoutSeconds=60, maxInstances=15){
        let config = functions.config()
        let enviornment = config.app.enviornment;
        if (enviornment == 'local') {
            return {
                timeoutSeconds:  60,
                maxInstances: 2,
                vpcConnector : "******",
                vpcConnectorEgressSettings: '*********'
            }
        } else  {
            return {
                timeoutSeconds:  timeoutSeconds != null ? timeoutSeconds: 60,
                // memory: '2GB',
                // retry: true,
                maxInstances: maxInstances != null ? maxInstances: 15,
                vpcConnector : "********",
                vpcConnectorEgressSettings: '**********'
            }
        }
    }
```

I am exploring GitHub secrets along with GitHub Actions to deploy firebase function on cloud. In my app I am using firebase.config() methods to retrieve my secret values like environment etc. which I want to put in GitHub secrets and want to retrieve from there instead of retrieving it from functions.config() method. Is there any way to do so, if yes please share it here with a short example.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63659938/how-to-use-github-secrets-in-firebase-cloud-functions) ? Because for such things there is [Secret parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#secret_parameters) exist within the firebase functions with that you can configure your environment.

Comment: Does my comment help ? If so acknowledge I can post as an answer so other community members will get help from this one.

Comment: Hi I have posted answer can you take a look ?

Answer (score 1):

For configuring the firebase functions environment you can use **defineString** combinations as follows :

```js
const { onRequest } = require('firebase-functions/v2/https');
const { defineInt } = require('firebase-functions/params');
const minInstancesConfig = defineInt('EXAMPLE_MININSTANCES');

export const example = onRequest(
  { minInstances: minInstancesConfig },
  (req, res) => { }
)
```

And to delegate between development and production

```js
const { onRequest } = require('firebase-functions/v2/https');
const environment = params.defineString(‘ENVIRONMENT’, {default: 'dev'});

// use built-in comparators
const minInstancesConfig = environment.equals('PRODUCTION').thenElse(10, 1);
export const helloWorld = onRequest(
  { minInstances: minInstancesConfig },
  (req, res) => { }
)
```

As per your function configuration you have to configure like this way and offcourse you can use these tricks on global configuration using `setGlobalOptions` as well like :

```js
const {setGlobalOptions} = require("firebase-functions/v2/options");
const environment = params.defineString(‘ENVIRONMENT’, {default: 'dev'});

// use built-in comparators
const minInstancesConfig = environment.equals('PRODUCTION').thenElse(10, 1);

setGlobalOptions({maxInstances: minInstancesConfig});
```

Reference : **[Parameter values and expressions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#parameter_values_and_expressions)**